# Fabric get() progressbar

Tags: python, fabric

I am currently generating a python-script with the fabric framwork that is supposed to collect a backup from a remote server and store it locally on the client running fabric.

Now, since the backup file is >400MB, it takes quite some time to transfer it. And here is where my question bumps in:

Is there any kind of progressbars for the fabric get()-function? Or rather, is it possible to add a progressbar somehow?

Here's a piece of my code:

```
def collect_backup():
    env.warn_only=True
    run('uptime')
    print "Copying scrips to be run..."
    filename, remotepath = _getlatest()
    print "Copy complete."
    print "Collecting backup..."
    localpath = _collect(filename, remotepath)

def _collect(filename, remotepath):
    a=remotepath + filename
    localpath="/home/bcns/backups/"
    ####Here's the get() I was talking about
    get(a, localpath)
    return(localpath)
```

The "filename" and "remotepath" variables are set in another function.

Comment: You're going to have to add a progress bar into a separate thread.  Do you just want something that will run in a console window or are you using a GUI?

Comment: Not using a GUI, just a terminal.

Comment: There's a fork that does this, see https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/236#issuecomment-47955224

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a lot of great info at the following site:

http://thelivingpearl.com/2012/12/31/creating-progress-bars-with-python/

Here is their solution for a console prog bar with threading:

```
import sys
import time
import threading

class progress_bar_loading(threading.Thread):

    def run(self):
            global stop
            global kill
            print 'Loading....  ',
            sys.stdout.flush()
            i = 0
            while stop != True:
                    if (i%4) == 0: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b/')
                    elif (i%4) == 1: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b-')
                    elif (i%4) == 2: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b\\')
                    elif (i%4) == 3: 
                        sys.stdout.write('\b|')

                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    time.sleep(0.2)
                    i+=1

            if kill == True: 
                print '\b\b\b\b ABORT!',
            else: 
                print '\b\b done!',


kill = False      
stop = False
p = progress_bar_loading()
p.start()

try:
    #anything you want to run. 
    time.sleep(1)
    stop = True
except KeyboardInterrupt or EOFError:
         kill = True
         stop = True
```

Hope that helps or at least gets you started.